# array_search function returns false even if string exist

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to find the `key` of an array value in an array. So i tried `array_search()` to do this. Which should return key if it found the value and false if there is no equal value present. In here am getting `false` even the string(`testing@example.com`) is exist.

```
    <?php
    $one = array('testing@example.com','example@example.com');
    $two = array('testing@example.com');
    var_dump(array_search($one,$two)); // getting false even the string exist, 
     //am i missing any thing
    ?>
```

I get false, is this because of `@` symbol in the string? i don't know. Can anyone give a idea on this?

Comment: did u read the manual of http://in1.php.net/array_search ?

Comment: In array_search()  first parameter(search string) must be string and parameter is your array.

Comment: I read the document. I'm new at programming. I couldn't found that first parameter needs to be string in doc. Can you help me to identify these things so that i can find it next time. @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: The first parameter doesn't have to be a string, but the first parameter is the value you're searching _for_, and the second parameter is the array you're searching _in_. The parameter names are a bit idiomatic (it looks for a 'needle' in a 'haystack'), so if English isn't your first language, that probably doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, Now i understand so needle is searching value. What is mean by  haystack @Michelle

Comment: yes in the doc u should always look at the parameters needed for the function and how they should be send. `mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )` here the first param `needle The searched value. ` `If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner. ` and in your case u are sending it as array hence failing.

Answer (score 4):

To use [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) in your case you have to give as a first parameter just string - not an array:

```
$one = array('testing@example.com','example@example.com');
$two = array('testing@example.com');
var_dump(array_search('testing@example.com',$two));
```

Then it will work.

If you want to find all values from array `$one` in array `$two`, use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$intersection = array_intersect('testing@example.com',$two);
```

then check if found with simple [`count`](http://php.net/count):

```
var_dump( count($intersection) > 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

`0` means `false` in php and `array_search` return array keys, you should use `===` operator to check

```
 if(array_search($one,$two) !== false )
      // exists
```

> **Warning** This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE`. Please read the section on
> Booleans for more information. Use the `=== operator` for testing the
> return value of this function.

[REFERENCE](https://www.php.net/array_search)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$one = array('testing@example.com','example@example.com');
$two = array('testing@example.com');
var_dump(array_search($two,$one));
```

Answer (score 1):

[see: function array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-search.php)

you can just reverse

```
$one
```

and 
    $two

```
 var_dump(array_search($two,$one));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $one = array('testing@example.com','example@example.com');
    $two = array('testing@example.com');
    var_dump(in_array($two, $one)); // true
    // also, isset more fast in case when $two is string:
    $two = 'testing@example.com';
    var_dump(isset($one[$two])); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

In `array_search` it checks that first parameter is in the second parameter.

`array_search($one,$two)`

You are checking the larger array in smaller array.

what you should  do is check smaller array is in larger array like this

`array_search($two,$one)`